# Findbugs, PMD or Checkstyle rule to find access by a field

Tags: java, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

I have a class caches a set of values internally.  These values can be updated periodically and the cached contents will be updated appropriately.   As long as users of this class do something like:

```
...
public void anyMethod(anyParams) {
    AnyObject value = CacheClass.getValue(anyKey);
    ...
}
```

Then life will be fine as that "value" will not maintained locally.  However if anyone does something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private AnyObject value = CacheClass.getValue(someKey);
   ...
}
```

Then if the cached value is updated the usage of it may not see the new value.

We use findbugs, checkstyle and PMD in the builds via Sonar.  So I am wondering if there is a way to define a rule in any of these systems to detect and flag the second type of usage above.  I have never written a rule in any these systems so would appreciate as much advice as possible (like, "well it can be done, but you really don't want to go there..." :)

Comment: A short lived class (like SimpleDateFormat) might even reasonably store the object in a field.
The first step would be to use an alerting naming: `CacheClass.retrieveValue(anyKey)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following XPath on your AST Node will catch Field declarations that calls your CacheClass method.

```
//FieldDeclaration[//PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image='CacheClass.getValue']
```

[How to write PMD Custom Rule](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.4/howtowritearule.html)

Comment: Thanks!  Let me just verify this then I'll check your answer.